# How to I fill the entire horizontal space of a table cell?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to make these divs on my table to fill the entire space of the cell even when there isn't enough content.

If you see below, the first cell (data_cell1_lt) isn't filled all the way horizontally with text so it make the apple image (data_cell3_lt) shift to the left.

The next two rows of text and images are lines up perfectly, but that's just because there is enough text to fill the entire cell.

http://jsfiddle.net/UMf3k/106/

```
<div class="wrapper-data">
    <div class="data_row">
        <div class="data_cell1_lt">
            <p>Fill the entire space.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="data_cell2_lt">
            &nbsp;</div>
        <div class="data_cell3_lt">
            <img alt="Apple" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/3/m/v/Y/E/V/small-red-apple-th.png" style="width: 96px; height: 99px;" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="data_row">
        <div class="data_cell1_lt">
            <p>Fill the entire space.Fill the entire space.Fill the entire space.Fill the entire space.Fill the entire space.Fill the entire space.Fill the entire space.Fill the entire space.Fill the entire space.Fill the entire space.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="data_cell2_lt">
            &nbsp;</div>
        <div class="data_cell3_lt">
            <img alt="Apple" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/3/m/v/Y/E/V/small-red-apple-th.png" style="width: 96px; height: 99px;" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="data_row">
        <div class="data_cell1_lt">
            <p><p>Fill the entire space.Fill the entire space.Fill the entire space.Fill the entire space.Fill the entire space.Fill the entire space.Fill the entire space.Fill the entire space.Fill the entire space.Fill the entire space.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="data_cell2_lt">
            &nbsp;</div>
        <div class="data_cell3_lt">
            <img alt="Apple" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/3/m/v/Y/E/V/small-red-apple-th.png" style="width: 96px; height: 99px;" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `data_row` a width of `100%` and it should work.

The reason being, `data_row` is displaying as an inline block.

Comment: Yes, I am aware. Why do you ask?

Comment: What would be the best practices to add space in between the data rows?

Comment: I'd add a few pixels to the `margin-bottom` or `padding`

Answer (score 0):

do you want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/UMf3k/109/)?

i just added `width: 100%;` at .data-row class

Answer (score 0):

Add a width of 100% to the data_row class:

```
.data_row {
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
    display:table;
    width:100%;        
}
```